# Getting always to thread 1 exc_bad_access in main.m

Tags: ios, iphone

When i running my app in few seconds i get into the main.m with an error, `thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1, addres=0x59)`, i tried setting up a `breakpoint` with All `expceptions` and also tried enabling zombies, but always get into the same spot. How can i debug this?

[image]

Comment: To help break on the actual exception you need to add a global exception breakpoint - http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: I have a global exception of course, but always gets me into there.

Comment: Something is happening with your SKShapeNode.  That's all we can tell.  Did you enable zombies to try to track this down?

Comment: Yes, i enabled zombies but i get into the same spot always. I've noticed i get this error on the iphone, but i can't reproduce it with on the simulator. This makes no sense for me